# how to get rid of an bom error in a json/php file

Tags: php, json, byte-order-mark

I spent a couple of hours to find this really simple error. I hope this little tutorial helps some else to solve this problem faster.

It had an invalid json file, which I created with my php code:
[image]

At the end of the file was a invisible character - a byte order mark (BOM). I converted my file to "UTF without BOM":

[image]

I replaced all BOMs:

```
preg_replace('/^\xef\xbb\xbf/', '', $string);
```

but nothing helped. Then I changed the view to hex (UltraEdit German: STRG + H, Ultraedit English: CTRL + H):

[image]

**Solution:**

To make a long story short: I just deleted the last character ">" and the BOM was gone:

[image]

Really stupid to waste some hours for such a simple solution. Maybe this helps someone else.